# Form success isn't displaying as successful

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.0.0-beta.4/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" integrity="sha384-R80DC0KVBO4GSTw+wZ5x2zn2pu4POSErBkf8/fSFhPXHxvHJydT0CSgAP2Yo2r4I" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group has-success">
    <label class="form-control-label question" for="answer-1">What is 5+5?</label>
    <input class="answer form-control form-control-success" id="answer-1" type="text" name="answer-1" value="10">
</div>
```

I tried to follow [the first example here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#examples).

It should be outlining the text input in green but it isn't.

Comment: Are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: @Madhavan.V no I'm not–you can run the code yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet",href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.0.0-beta.4/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" integrity="sha384-R80DC0KVBO4GSTw+wZ5x2zn2pu4POSErBkf8/fSFhPXHxvHJydT0CSgAP2Yo2r4I" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group has-success">
    <label class="form-control-label question" for="answer-1">What is 5+5?</label>
    <input class="answer form-control form-control-success" id="answer-1" type="text" name="answer-1" value="10">
</div>
```

Comment: So this feature is only available in alpha bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Use js function for validate as below,

```js
function check(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.value && +e.target.value === 10) return e.target.style.borderColor = 'green';
  return e.target.style.borderColor = 'red';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" ,href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.0.0-beta.4/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" integrity="sha384-R80DC0KVBO4GSTw+wZ5x2zn2pu4POSErBkf8/fSFhPXHxvHJydT0CSgAP2Yo2r4I" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group has-success">
  <label class="form-control-label question" for="answer-1">What is 5+5?</label>
  <input class="answer form-control form-control-success" id="answer-1" type="text" name="answer-1" onkeyup="check(event)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you missed css link somehow,, this is correct one, and you do not need `jQuery` for that, that is only `css` based coloring

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="form-group has-success">
      <label class="form-control-label question" for="answer-1">What is 5+5?</label>
      <input class="answer form-control form-control-success" id="answer-1" type="text" name="answer-1" value="10">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so this feature only available in alpha bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, using Bootstrap 4 beta 2. I've added the `bmd-form-group is-focused` classes to the div.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.0.0-beta.4/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" integrity="sha384-R80DC0KVBO4GSTw+wZ5x2zn2pu4POSErBkf8/fSFhPXHxvHJydT0CSgAP2Yo2r4I" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="bmd-form-group is-focused">
  <label class="form-control-label question" for="answer-1">What is 5+5?</label>
  <input class="answer form-control is-valid" id="answer-1" type="text" name="answer-1" value="10">
</div>
```

Next time you check the Bootstrap docs, use the current beta docs at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/